# How to animate Rectangle in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I want to learn some tricks about JAVA for my project.

I want to animate my Rectangle leftoright and righttoleft but I can't apply the same functions for ball animation.

In addition,how can I start my ball in different x-direction with a border of y-coordinate ?

Thanks a lot for your advices and helping.

[image]

**My codes:**

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MultipleBall extends JApplet {
public MultipleBall() {
    add(new BallControl());
}

class BallControl extends JPanel {
    private BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel();
    private JButton Suspend = new JButton("Suspend");
    private JButton Resume = new JButton("Resume");
    private JButton Add = new JButton("+1");
    private JButton Subtract = new JButton("-1");
    private JScrollBar Delay = new JScrollBar();

    public BallControl() {
        // Group buttons in a panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(Suspend);
        panel.add(Resume);
        panel.add(Add);
        panel.add(Subtract);

        // Add ball and buttons to the panel
        ballPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.red));
        Delay.setOrientation(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
        ballPanel.setDelay(Delay.getMaximum());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(Delay, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(ballPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Register listeners
        Suspend.addActionListener(new Listener());
        Resume.addActionListener(new Listener());
        Add.addActionListener(new Listener());
        Subtract.addActionListener(new Listener());
        Delay.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                ballPanel.setDelay(Delay.getMaximum() - e.getValue());
            }
        });
    }

    class Listener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == Suspend)
                ballPanel.suspend();
            else if (e.getSource() == Resume)
                ballPanel.resume();
            else if (e.getSource() == Add)
                ballPanel.add();
            else if (e.getSource() == Subtract)
                ballPanel.subtract();
        }
    }
}

class BallPanel extends JPanel {
    private int delay = 30;
    private ArrayList<Ball> list = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    // Create a timer with the initial delay
    protected Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
        /** Handle the action event */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });

    public BallPanel() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void add() {
        list.add(new Ball());
    }

    public void subtract() {
        if (list.size() > 0)
            list.remove(list.size() - 1); // Remove the last ball
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(185, 279, 50, 15);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(185, 279, 50, 15);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Ball ball = (Ball) list.get(i); // Get a ball
            g.setColor(ball.color); // Set ball color

            // Check boundaries
            if (ball.x < 0 || ball.x > getWidth())
                ball.dx = -ball.dx;

            if (ball.y < 0 || ball.y > getHeight())
                ball.dy = -ball.dy;

            // Adjust ball position
            ball.x += ball.dx;
            // ball.y += ball.dy;
            g.fillOval(ball.x - ball.radius, ball.y - ball.radius,
                    ball.radius * 2, ball.radius * 2);
        }
    }

    public void suspend() {
        timer.stop();
    }

    public void resume() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
        timer.setDelay(delay);
    }
}

class Ball {
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20; // Current ball position
    int dx = 2; // Increment on ball's x-coordinate
    int dy = 2; // Increment on ball's y-coordinate
    int radius = 15; // Ball radius
    Color color = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256),
            (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));
}

/** Main method */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JApplet applet = new MultipleBallApp();
    frame.add(applet);
    frame.setTitle("MultipleBallApp");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I got the comment and I understand what you wanted. Also, what do you want with the rectangle?

Comment: You inability to implement a solution is not necessarily make the solution wrong. If you have problems, ask a question in the comments, trying artibitarly wipe out a persons answer is not how SO works. I apologise as I was trying to get the answer up while feeding my daughter so it didn't quite come up the way I wanted it to. I've updated the answer we a better code sample. If you have an issue, ask and I and/or others will try and help you further.

Answer (score 4):

> can't apply the same functions for ball animation

This is probably your first mistake.  In fact, this is exactly what you should be trying to do.  The idea is, you should be trying to devise a means by what is painted/animated is abstract so it doesn't matter what the shape is you want to paint, you can apply it to the sam basic animation process...

For example, you could start with some kind `interface` which describes the basic properties of an animated entity...

```
public interface AnimatedShape {
    public void update(Rectangle bounds);
    public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

This says that an animated entity can be updated (moved) and painted.  By convention (and because I'm lazy), I like to create an `abstract` implementation which implements the most common aspects...

```
public abstract class AbstractAnimatedShape implements AnimatedShape {

    private Rectangle bounds;
    private int dx, dy;

    public AbstractAnimatedShape() {
    }

    public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    public int getDx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public int getDy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public void setDx(int dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    public void setDy(int dy) {
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Rectangle parentBounds) {
        Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
        int dx = getDx();
        int dy = getDy();
        bounds.x += dx;
        bounds.y += dy;
        if (bounds.x  < parentBounds.x) {
            bounds.x = parentBounds.x;
            setDx(dx *= -1);
        } else if (bounds.x + bounds.width > parentBounds.x + parentBounds.width) {
            bounds.x = parentBounds.x + (parentBounds.width - bounds.width);
            setDx(dx *= -1);
        }
        if (bounds.y < parentBounds.y) {
            bounds.y = parentBounds.y;
            setDy(dy *= -1);
        } else if (bounds.y + bounds.height > parentBounds.y + parentBounds.height) {
            bounds.y = parentBounds.y + (parentBounds.height - bounds.height);
            setDy(dy *= -1);
        }
    }
}
```

And then start creating implementations...

```
public class AnimatedBall extends AbstractAnimatedShape {

    private Color color;

    public AnimatedBall(int x, int y, int radius, Color color) {
        setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2));
        this.color = color;
        setDx(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : -2);
        setDy(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : -2);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d) {
        Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        g2d.fillOval(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }
}
```

In this manner, you can customise the way that the entity is animated and painted, but the basic logic for each instance of the entity is the same...

But what's all the point of this...

Basically, what it allows us to do is produce a "virtual" concept of all the animated objects and simplify there management, for example...

Instead of using a "tightly" coupled `List`, we can use a loosely couple `List` instead...

```
private ArrayList<AnimatedShape> list = new ArrayList<AnimatedShape>();
```

Then when we want the entities to be updated, we simply need to iterate the `List` and ask the entities to update...

```
protected Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (AnimatedShape ball : list) {
            ball.update(getBounds());
        }
        repaint();
    }
});
```

And when they need to be painted...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (AnimatedShape ball : list) {
        ball.paint(this, g2d);
    }
}
```

Because the `BallPane` doesn't care what actually type of entity it is, but only that it's a type of `AnimatedShape`...makes life easier...

Now, my implementation of the `AnimatedBall` already randomise the direction of each instance of the ball, but you can also randomise the starting position when the ball is added using something like...

```
public void add() {
    int radius = 15;
    // Randomised position
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * (getWidth() - (radius * 2))) + radius;
    int y = (int)(Math.random() * (getHeight() - (radius * 2))) + radius;
    Color color = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256),
                    (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));

    AnimatedBall ball = new AnimatedBall(x, y, radius, color);

    list.add(ball);
}
```

But how does this help you with adding a rectangle?

You now need to create an `AnimatedRectangle` that extends from `AbstractAnimatedShape` and implemented the required methods and add instances of this to the `List` of `AnimatedShape`s in the `BallPane`.

If you don't want the rectangle to be managed within the same list, you could create another list and manage it sepearatly (it create two additional methods, `update(List<AnimatedShape>)` and `paint(List<AnimatedShape>, Graphics2D)` passing in each individual list so as to reduce the duplicate code, but that's me)...

You can restrict the rectangles vertical movement by overriding the `setDy` method and ignoring any changes, for example

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MultipleBall {

    public MultipleBall() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MultipleBallApp");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new BallControl());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BallControl extends JPanel {

        private BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel();
        private JButton Suspend = new JButton("Suspend");
        private JButton Resume = new JButton("Resume");
        private JButton Add = new JButton("+1");
        private JButton Subtract = new JButton("-1");
        private JScrollBar Delay = new JScrollBar();

        public BallControl() {
            // Group buttons in a panel
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(Suspend);
            panel.add(Resume);
            panel.add(Add);
            panel.add(Subtract);

            // Add ball and buttons to the panel
            ballPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.red));
            Delay.setOrientation(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
            ballPanel.setDelay(Delay.getMaximum());
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(Delay, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(ballPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            // Register listeners
            Suspend.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Resume.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Add.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Subtract.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Delay.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

                public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                    ballPanel.setDelay(Delay.getMaximum() - e.getValue());
                }
            });
        }

        class Listener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == Suspend) {
                    ballPanel.suspend();
                } else if (e.getSource() == Resume) {
                    ballPanel.resume();
                } else if (e.getSource() == Add) {
                    ballPanel.add();
                } else if (e.getSource() == Subtract) {
                    ballPanel.subtract();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class BallPanel extends JPanel {

        private int delay = 30;
        private ArrayList<AnimatedShape> list = new ArrayList<AnimatedShape>();
        private AnimatedRectange rectangle;

        public BallPanel() {
            this.rectangle = new AnimatedRectange(-25, 200, 50, 25, Color.RED);

            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        // Create a timer with the initial delay
        protected Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
            /**
             * Handle the action event
             */
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (AnimatedShape ball : list) {
                    ball.update(getBounds());
                }
                rectangle.update(getBounds());
                repaint();
            }
        });

        public void add() {
            int radius = 15;
            // Randomised position
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() - (radius * 2))) + radius;
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() - (radius * 2))) + radius;
            Color color = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256),
                            (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));

            AnimatedBall ball = new AnimatedBall(x, y, radius, color);

            list.add(ball);
        }

        public void subtract() {
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                list.remove(list.size() - 1); // Remove the last ball
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (AnimatedShape ball : list) {
                ball.paint(this, g2d);
            }
            rectangle.paint(this, g2d);
        }

        public void suspend() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        public void resume() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void setDelay(int delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
            timer.setDelay(delay);
        }
    }

    public interface AnimatedShape {

        public void update(Rectangle bounds);

        public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d);
    }

    public abstract class AbstractAnimatedShape implements AnimatedShape {

        private Rectangle bounds;
        private int dx, dy;

        public AbstractAnimatedShape() {
        }

        public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
            this.bounds = bounds;
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        public int getDx() {
            return dx;
        }

        public int getDy() {
            return dy;
        }

        public void setDx(int dx) {
            this.dx = dx;
        }

        public void setDy(int dy) {
            this.dy = dy;
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Rectangle parentBounds) {
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            int dx = getDx();
            int dy = getDy();
            bounds.x += dx;
            bounds.y += dy;
            if (bounds.x  < parentBounds.x) {
                bounds.x = parentBounds.x;
                setDx(dx *= -1);
            } else if (bounds.x + bounds.width > parentBounds.x + parentBounds.width) {
                bounds.x = parentBounds.x + (parentBounds.width - bounds.width);
                setDx(dx *= -1);
            }
            if (bounds.y < parentBounds.y) {
                bounds.y = parentBounds.y;
                setDy(dy *= -1);
            } else if (bounds.y + bounds.height > parentBounds.y + parentBounds.height) {
                bounds.y = parentBounds.y + (parentBounds.height - bounds.height);
                setDy(dy *= -1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AnimatedBall extends AbstractAnimatedShape {

        private Color color;

        public AnimatedBall(int x, int y, int radius, Color color) {
            setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2));
            this.color = color;
            setDx(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : -2);
            setDy(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : -2);
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d) {
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            g2d.setColor(getColor());
            g2d.fillOval(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }
    }

    public class AnimatedRectange extends AbstractAnimatedShape {

        private Color color;

        public AnimatedRectange(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
            setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
            this.color = color;
            setDx(2);
        }

        // Don't want to adjust the vertical speed
        @Override
        public void setDy(int dy) {
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d) {
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fill(bounds);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Main method
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultipleBall();
    }
}
```

**Amendment**

- You really should avoid adding `JApplet` to a `JFrame`, an applet has a prescribed life cycle and management process which you are ignoring.  Better to focus on just using the `BallControl` panel as the core UI element and then add this to what ever top level container you want
- You may find a [`JSlider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) more piratical then a `JScrollBar`, not to mention, it will look better on different platforms, most uses understand what a slider is used for...

Comment: Make a separate animated shape, called something like AnimatedRectangle. Implement the update and paint methods. Use the update method to move the object left and right by modifying the bounds.x and dx property, as demonstrated in the AnimatedBall, use fillRect in the paint method (in fact, y choi

Comment: Sorry, got cut off, you could actually use `g2d.fill(getBounds())` to make it simpler

Comment: Yes, but if you use the bounds of the object yourself, you can fill it simply, rather then having to use `fillRect`, the `Rectangle` describes the individual animated objects position and size, this can be used to paint with as well ;)

Comment: Ok I understand MadProgrammer what will I do.Now,I will add some specifications to my code about mouseclik operation and limiting the ball x coordinate in a one point.

Comment: I did the "limiting the ball y-coordinate by

setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y / 2**, radius * 2, radius * 2));

Comment: I wrote the wrong thing about the limiting ball coordinate,the correct one is limiting the y-coordinate.But,I did it .MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

Add a static variable like ballCount and add 1 to it every time you make a ball. In the `Ball` class, change the definition of y to something like`y = 20 + ballcount*(radius*2+distanceInBalls)`

```
public class RandomTests extends JApplet {


    public RandomTests() {
        add(new BallControl());
    }

    static int ballCount = 0;

    class BallControl extends JPanel {
        private BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel();
        private JButton Suspend = new JButton("Suspend");
        private JButton Resume = new JButton("Resume");
        private JButton Add = new JButton("+1");
        private JButton Subtract = new JButton("-1");
        private JScrollBar Delay = new JScrollBar();

        public BallControl() {
            // Group buttons in a panel
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(Suspend);
            panel.add(Resume);
            panel.add(Add);
            panel.add(Subtract);

            // Add ball and buttons to the panel
            ballPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.red));
            Delay.setOrientation(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
            ballPanel.setDelay(Delay.getMaximum());
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(Delay, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(ballPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            // Register listeners
            Suspend.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Resume.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Add.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Subtract.addActionListener(new Listener());
            Delay.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

                public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                    ballPanel.setDelay(Delay.getMaximum() - e.getValue());
                }
            });
        }

        class Listener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == Suspend) ballPanel.suspend();
                else if (e.getSource() == Resume) ballPanel.resume();
                else if (e.getSource() == Add) ballPanel.add();
                else if (e.getSource() == Subtract) ballPanel.subtract();
            }
        }
    }

    class BallPanel extends JPanel {
        private int delay = 30;
        private ArrayList<Ball> list = new ArrayList<Ball>();

        // Create a timer with the initial delay
        protected Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
            /** Handle the action event */
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });

        public BallPanel() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void add() {
            list.add(new Ball());
            ballCount++;
        }

        public void subtract() {
            if (list.size() > 0) list.remove(list.size() - 1); // Remove the last ball
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(185, 279, 50, 15);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(185, 279, 50, 15);

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Ball ball = (Ball) list.get(i); // Get a ball
                g.setColor(ball.color); // Set ball color

                // Check boundaries
                if (ball.x < 0 || ball.x > getWidth()) ball.dx = -ball.dx;

                if (ball.y < 0 || ball.y > getHeight()) ball.dy = -ball.dy;

                // Adjust ball position
                ball.x += ball.dx;
                // ball.y += ball.dy;
                g.fillOval(ball.x - ball.radius, ball.y - ball.radius, ball.radius * 2, ball.radius * 2);
            }
        }

        public void suspend() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        public void resume() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void setDelay(int delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
            timer.setDelay(delay);
        }
    }

    class Ball {
        int radius = 15; // Ball radius
        int x = radius;
        int y = 20 + (radius * ballCount * 2 + 15); // Current ball position
        int dx = 2; // Increment on ball's x-coordinate
        int dy = 2; // Increment on ball's y-coordinate
        Color color = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JApplet applet = new RandomTests();
        frame.add(applet);
        frame.setTitle("MultipleBallApp");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every where it says RandomTests, change it to your class name.

Comment: You mean when it reaches x=150, it jumps to start instead of animating back?

Comment: Where you have the comment `//Check boundries` remove the code and add the line `if(ball.x>150) ball.x = 0;` and also add the line `if(ballcounts>0)ballCounts--;` in the subtract method

Comment: Dude you have  to use correct English. I don't understand you.

Comment: Why? The balls are contained in List, why not use the List.size? You should avoid static where you can, especially where more the one instance of a class might rely on it

Comment: @usama8800 No there isn't, there's only one controlling class, the `BallPane` class and from this, we know how many shapes there are...