# How to move a circle automatically in java?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe, awt

I am new to java GUI, and am trying to learn it. I want to move a circle on screen automatically(i.e not by pressing any key or doing any other action). I found a way to move it by doing some action but thats not what i needed. Please could anybody tell me the simplest way of doing that?

I want to remove the action listener in the following code, so that circles move automatically:

```
public class MyFirstGraphics extends JFrame {

    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    MyFirstGraphics() {
        super("Circle");
        setSize(800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.pink);
        JButton f = new JButton("circle");
        f.addActionListener(new re());
        add(f, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private class re implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
                x++;
                y++;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFirstGraphics l = new MyFirstGraphics();
        l.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815472/how-to-animate-rectangle-in-jpanel/23817255#23817255) (scroll to the bottom). You should also have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details about how it is achieved

Comment: Animation is also not a simple subject (fun, but not simple). The linked example in the above comment is about as simple as it gets for Swing

Comment: *"I found a way to move it by doing some action but thats not what i needed."* For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example) of that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson posted a sample code.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets start with the fact that animation is the illusion of change over time.  Also, Swing is a single threaded environment.  You can't "block" the Swing thread (aka the Event Dispatching Thread) and have it paint updates, you need some way to schedule updates at a regular bases so you can apply a change and then have the change repainted...

So your first problem is in your `actionPerformed` method...

```
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    x++;
    y++;
    repaint();
}
```

Basically, the only thing that will get painted is the ball at 150x150, nothing else in between will be painted.

Instead, you need to change it to something more like...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (x < 150 && y < 150) {
        x++;
        y++;
    } else {
        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Take a look at:

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

For more details

**A basic "bouncy" ball example**

[image: Bounce]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BounceyDot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BounceyDot();
    }

    public BounceyDot() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 100;
        private int radius = 20;
        private int xDelta = 2;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    x += xDelta;
                    if (x + (radius * 2) > getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - (radius * 2);
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! That was just the exact thing i was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To animate that code, use a Swing based `Timer` with the `re` `ActionListener` as one argument in the constructor (the other argument is the delay).

See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details and working examples.